# Parameterize the join condition in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of column names which varies every time. The column names are stored in a list. So, I need to pass the column names from the list (in the below example its id and programid) to compare between source and target dataframe. In the example below, i want to check if `src_id == id` and `src_programid == programid`.

```python
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

srccolumns = ['src_id','src_programid']
tgtcolumns = ['id','programid']

joinSrcTgtAction =  joinSrcTgt.withColumn(
    'action', 
    when(
        (
            (col(src_id) == col(id)) & 
            (col(src_programid) == col(programid)) & 
            (joinSrcTgt.src_checksum != joinSrcTgt.checksum)
        ),
        'upsert'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lists have the same size and guarantee the order of the column names, so we can match a pair by index, you could do something like the following:

```
src_columns = ['src_id','src_programid']
tgt_columns = ['id','programid']

condition = True
for i in range(0, len(src_columns)):
    condition &= (join_src_tgt[src_columns[i]] == join_src_tgt[dest_columns[i]])

join_src_tgt_action =  join_src_tgt.withColumn(
    'action', 
    when(condition & (join_src_tgt.src_checksum != join_src_tgt.checksum), 'upsert')
)
```

Comment: @Shivhar if it worked, make you sure you accept the answer (the little checkmark on the left of the answer) :)

Comment: Well, maybe you wanna detail what doesn't work? do you get any error?